# hyperlink isn't working in mac firefox browser

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox

I am facing an  issue on my site. On my site, the a tag text hyperlink isn't working in mac Firefox browser (whether you are giving target blank or not with the a tag, the issue is remain same). But its work fine in other mac browser like chrome, safari or opera. In windows machine, the link is working fine in all browsers. But its not working in mac Firefox. When there is an image link with the a tag, that time the link is working fine. But when the link is with a text, then its not working in mac Firefox browser. I really don't know whether anyone have encountered similar kind of situation before or not. It would be a great help for me if someone can give me an idea how to sort this out.

The code is like the following:

```
<p>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/mts">
<img src="/images/mtss/icon_facebook.png">
</a>
Click
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/mts">here</a>
to follow mts on Facebook
</p>
```

In the above code, the image is get hyperlinked in all the browser but the text "here" is hyperlinked all the browsers except mac Firefox browser.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of what the link looks like?

Answer (score 1):

This might be something to do with the configuration settings of Firefox in the problematic system

1. Open Firefox
2. In the URL, type `about:config`
3. If presented with a warning, click the button and proceed to next page
4. In the search text box on top, type '`dom.popup_allowed_events`'. In the value column, make sure that it has following events '`change click dblclick mouseup reset submit touchend`'
5. Close the browser and try your code

If the click event is not allowed to open a popup (i.e. _blank), it would be captured by Firefox as a popup and you'd see that yellow bar on top

Comment: @indy The default configuration is the one provided in this answer, your users will not likely face this issue. Also, if they had modified it, it's probably because they don't want to be bothered with popup windows, don't try to workaround this

Comment: @Kaiido actually the users are facing this issue. The default configuration is solving my problem but not all the users problem who are facing this issue.

Comment: Then remove the `target="_blank"` But your page might not be the only one where they're facing the issue so I would tell them to check their configuration.

Comment: @Kaiido its not a target="_blank" issue. I have removed the target blank but the behavior is still the same. Not working in mac firefox browser only. Also I have checked the configuration and in 39 version of Firefox, that option is already there 'change click dblclick mouseup reset submit touchend'..so there has to be something else.

Comment: Then go back to [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397119/hyperlink-isnt-working-in-mac-firefox-browser#comment-50769897)

Comment: @Kaiido In your first comment, you mentioned about the default configuration is the answer. But as I said in 39 version of Firefox, that option is already there. In about:config, under type 'dom.popup_allowed_events', the value column is already showing like this 'change click dblclick mouseup reset submit touchend'..so what to change in here. Its already there in firefox and still not working. Any other idea?

Comment: No I mean the first comment on your question, [follow the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397119/hyperlink-isnt-working-in-mac-firefox-browser#comment-50769897). Which is asking your for a code snippet, I would even add a working one, where we could reprodruce it (i.e http://jsfiddle.net/)